# RC oscillator with Wien bridge and JFET amplitude stabilizaton

Tags: wien-bridge

I need to make an RC oscillator with a Wien bridge and JFET amplitude stabilization, I have a schematic, but no formulas on how to calculate the values. I tried to look around the internet, but found nothing that works for me. Here is the schematic:
[image: RC oscillator]

Also the frequency should be 1 kHz, the amplitude 0-5 Vef and the output resistance lower than 100 Ω.

Here you can find similar schematics: https://www.sse-najizdarne.cz/dokumenty/studijni_materialy/ov/uc_text_oscil%C3%A1tory.pdf

Comment: Tadeas.grohmi - Hi, (a) You said: "*I have a schematic, but no formulas on how to calculate the values*" It sounds like you got the schematic from somewhere else (as you'd know the calculations if you had designed it). In order to comply with the Stack Exchange [rule for referencing](/help/referencing), which applies to material copied or adapted from elsewhere, we need you to [edit] your question & add a link to the schematic's source (or a written citation if it's an offline source). (b) Please see the main site rules in the [tour] & [help] as they differ from typical forums. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you test it in a simulator because formulas don't usually help when pots are involved or JFETs.

Comment: Here is an app note with values, see figure 3. https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN3846.pdf Note that I built this and couldn't get it to work. I am always working on multiple projects. so, if one frustrates me to much, I put it aside. I may come back to it someday.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. Im working on a simulation, but its a pain to get the wave to look like a good sin signal.

Comment: @Tadeas.grohmi - Hi, I see you added a link to a PDF, mentioning that it has "similar schematics". However I did not find the actual schematic which you copied into the question. Therefore currently your question still breaks the site rule about containing copied material without a reference for that material (adding a reference to *similar* material does not count). || Please can you explain what is stopping you from adding a reference to the source of that schematic? Then we can figure out how we can reasonably comply with the site rule. Thanks.

Comment: Built and tested jfet based circuit given here as an answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/623405/my-wien-bridge-oscillator-doesnt-work-what-could-the-problem-be

Answer (score 1):

Just try this simple circuit ... for starting the search.
Then you can add the JFET and the other components.
The last opamp is just a voltage "follower".

[image]

Adding JFET ...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit is different to the circuit recommended by Texas instruments:

[image: Wien bridge oscillator]

Answer (score 1):

Here are some basics:

- Oscillation frequency: w=1/RC. You should try to use two resistors R in the lower kOhm range and two capacitors not too small (no pico-Farads) and not too large (not in the upper micro-Farad range).
- The nominal gain of the opamp amplifier must be A=+3 (in practice some % larger because of the FET stabilization)
- The time constant of the FET-path Tf=C1*Rf (Rf is the effective R connected with C1) should be app. 10 times larger (at least) as the oscillation period T=2Pi * RC